# Split array by consecutive sequences

Tags: ruby, sorting, sequences

Given an array of integer such as:

```
array = [1,2,3,5,6,7,20,21,33,87,88,89,101]
```

This array contains `k` consecutive subsequences (in this case `k = 6`), such as "1,2,3" and "87,88,89". How do I get an array containing arrays of these `k` subsequences?

For the above example these would be:

```
[[1,2,3], [5,6,7], [20,21], [33], [87,88,89], [101]]
```

Comment: not understood! can you bit clarify the question?

Comment: updated the example to make it clearer (hopefully)

Comment: I don't see why this question still is closed, it seems someone has already clarified it. Anyway, the Ruby Core documentation has a similar example for explaining `slice_when`, which also would be the simplest and safest way to get the requested result:
`array.slice_when { |i, j| i+1 != j }`

Comment: array.slice_when { |e1, e2| (e1..e2).count > 2 }.to_a

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def seq_sort(array)
  finished = [array.first], i = 0

  array.each_cons(2) do |(a,b)|
    if b - a == 1
      finished[i] << b
    else
      finished[i += 1] = [b]
    end
  end

  finished
end

> seq_sort([1,2,38,39,92,94,103,104,105,1002])
=> [[1,2], [38, 39], [92], [94], [103, 104, 105], [1002]]
```

Comment: thanks! i 'finished = [[array.first]], i = 0' had to be changed to 'finished = [array.first], i = 0' to get the output intended. I'm giving you the answer because yours was first and would also be closer to how I probably would've answered it...if i had answered it :-)

Comment: I must've overlooked that in my tests! You should update your question to more clearly state what you want though. :-)

Comment: It's better to spread `finished = [[array.first]], i = 0` to different rows. Otherwise, you'll get `seq_sort([1,2,3,4,5]) => [[1,2,3,4,5], 0]`

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT:**

If you are using rails, there is an easy way, using the active support [split](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Array.html#method-i-split) method

```
def sort_it(arr)
  (arr.first..arr.last).to_a.split {|i| !arr.include?(i) }.select &:present?
end
```

or in Ruby

```
def sort_it(arr)
  tmp, main = [], []
  arr.each_with_index do |x, i|
    if arr[i-1]
      if arr[i-1] + 1 == x
        tmp << x
      else
        main << tmp unless tmp.empty?
        tmp = [x]
      end
    else
      tmp << x
    end
  end
  main << tmp
  main
end


> a = [1, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 14, 16, 27]
> sort_it(a)
=> [[1], [3], [5, 6], [8, 9], [11, 12, 13, 14], [16], [27]]
```

Comment: Thanks! Your answer is correct as well. But someone else's came first. I did learn something about array accessing and empty tho :-)

Comment: I have updated my answer with a solution for rails, in case u are using it. :)

Comment: This method for Ruby is fastest from all solutions in comments

Answer (score 4):

The unshifted `0` is a dummy. It could be any number.

```
[1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7]
.unshift(0)
.each_cons(2).slice_before{|m, n| m + 1 < n}.map{|a| a.map(&:last)}
# => [[1, 2, 3], [5, 6, 7]]
```

Comment: Thank you as well! Your code gives the right output too and was the shortest!